# WPF error: "Cannot add content to an object of type BarStaticItem"

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, datatemplate, contenttemplate

I have this XAML:

```
<dxb:BarStaticItem>
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyStatusBarText}"></TextBlock>
</dxb:BarStaticItem>
```

However, I'm getting this error:

`Cannot add content to an object of type BarStaticItem`

How do I fix this, so I can do things like change the color and style of the rendered item?

Answer (score 5):

**Assuming `BarStaticItem` is an `UserControl`...**

I'm using code behind in one partial cs file where (almost) everything is done, with an `ObservableCollection` of `UIElement` instead (or whatever element you want)

**1) Create a related partial Class called `BarStaticItem.Children.cs`, then add the required namespaces :**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel; // ObservableCollection.
using System.Collections.Specialized; // NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.
using System.Windows.Markup; // [ContentProperty()]
```

**2) add a `ContentProperty` flag above partial class declaration, then add your `Children` Property declaration :**

```
namespace YourNamespace.SubNamespace
{
    [ContentProperty("Children")] // <- here !
    public partial class BarStaticItem
    // (This is the related BarStaticItem.Children.cs file)
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Children Property of this BarStaticItem.
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<UIElement> Children { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

**3) Now create the ObservableCollection Property initializer** in a private method in the cs file :

```
        private void RegisterChildrenObservation()
        {
            Children = new ObservableCollection<UIElement>();
            Children.CollectionChanged += 
                new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(Children_CollectionChanged);
        }
```

**4) Call that initializer in the constructor of your custom UI Element :**

```
namespace YourNamespace.SubNamespace
{
    public partial class BarStaticItem : UserControl
    // (This is the base BarStaticItem.xaml.cs file)
    {
        public BarStaticItem()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            RegisterChildrenObservation(); // <- here !
        }
    }
}
```

**5) Handle the behaviour of your Children collection** in the BarStaticItem.Children.cs file by declaring the method handler you called in your initializer :

This is just plain formal procedure. Once you understand the whole thing, you'll see you can play around with it and create much more scenarios than what you could do with xaml alone. To begin with, only two states really matters here :

- `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add`
  and
- `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove`

  ```
  private void Children_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
      switch (e.Action)
      {
          case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
          {
              foreach (UIElement currentElement in e.NewItems)
              {
                  MyChildContainer.Children.Add(currentElement);
              }
              break;
          }

          case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
          {
              break;
          }

          case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
          {
              foreach (UIElement currentElement in e.OldItems)
              {
                  MyChildContainer.Children.Remove(currentElement);
              }
              break;
          }

          case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
          {
              break;
          }

          case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
          {
              break;
          }

          default:
          {
              break;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

**6) you're nearly done, but you must create and name an UIElement in your BarStaticItem.xaml file to contain the added UIElements :**

```
<UserControl ...>
    <Grid 
        x:Name="MyChildContainer"><!-- HERE ! -->
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

---

Then you're done, and you could add ANY Child Element to your BarStaticItem directly in the XAML just like you did.

```
<dxb:BarStaticItem>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyStatusBarText}"></TextBlock>
</dxb:BarStaticItem>
```

..and that `TextBlock` will land in the `Grid` defined and named `MyChildContainer` in the `BarStaticItem.xaml`. You could use a DockPanel or a StackPanel, even decide in which container the Child Element will go based on its type or update (Dependency) Properties in the `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add` case, like :

```
private void Children_CollectionChanged(
    object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Action)
    {
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
        {
            foreach (UIElement currentElement in e.NewItems)
            {
                if (currentElement.GetType() == typeof(TextBlock))
                {
                    TextBlock currentTextBlock = (TextBlock)currentElement;
                    // Manipulate your TextBlock...
                    HeaderTextBlockContainer.Children.Add(currentElement);
                }
                else if (currentElement.GetType() == typeof(Button))
                {
                    FooterButtonsDockPanel.Children.Add(currentElement);
                    DockPanel.SetDock(currentElement, Dock.Right);
                }
                else
                {
                    MainContentContainer.Children.Add(currentElement);
                }
                ContentDefined = true; // Custom Property.
            }
            //...
```

> Who DV you is not me

Answer (score 0):

This XAML will work fine, but its limiting (it won't allow you to set the color of the text displayed, as requested):

```
<dxb:BarStaticItem
    Content="{Binding MyStatusBarText}">
</dxb:BarStaticItem>
```

This particular control does allow us to set the `ContentTemplate`. We can use this to style the content:

```
<dxb:BarStaticItem
   ContentTemplate="????">
</dxb:BarStaticItem>
```

First, we define a `DataTemplate` in `Window.Resources`. This is what our `ContentTemplate` will point at:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyStatusBarContentTemplate">
        <!-- As the DataContext of a resource does not default to the window, we have to use RelativeSource to find the window. -->
        <TextBlock Name="MyText"                
            Text="{Binding Path=MyStatusBarText, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
            AncestorType=Window}}">                
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

As the `DataContext` of a `DataTemplate` is different to the rest of the XAML, if we omit the XAML `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}` then the binding will not work properly. Other than that, all we are doing is defining a template which can be used to render the contents of the control.

Then, we point our control at this `DataTemplate`:

```
<dxb:BarStaticItem
    ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource MyStatusBarContentTemplate}">
</dxb:BarStaticItem>
```

Now that we have defined a custom data template, we can do anything we want. For example, we could add a `Converter` which colored the text red if the status bar contained the text `Error` (something that was impossible, otherwise).

This answer also illustrates how it is possible to use a `DataTemplate` to display custom content for most controls.

**Update**

Rather than defining the `DataTemplate` in the resources for the Window, defined it as a resource for `BarStaticItem`. This keeps related items together in the XAML.

This particular XAML means that the status bar text automatically goes red if the text contains the string `Error`, and the status bar text is automatically prefixed with the time. Let me know if you want me to post the C# code for the converters.

```
<dxb:BarStaticItem
  ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource MyStatusBarContentTemplate}">
  <dxb:BarStaticItem.Resources>
      <DataTemplate x:Key="MyStatusBarContentTemplate">
          <!-- As the DataContext of a resource does not default to the window, we have to use RelativeSource to find the window. -->
          <TextBlock Name="MyText"
              Foreground="{Binding ElementName=MyText, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource ColorRedIfTextContainsError}}"
              Text="{Binding Path=SettingsGlobalViewModel.StatusBarText, 
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
              AncestorType=Window},
              Converter={StaticResource PrefixStringWithTime}}">
          </TextBlock>
      </DataTemplate>
  </dxb:BarStaticItem.Resources>
</dxb:BarStaticItem>
```

Comment: Would the mysterious downvoter care to elaborate why? This solution worked perfecly for me (it took me a while to figure out, which is why I'm posting it on SO for both myself and others to reference).

Comment: I just carefully re-read your answer.. after I wrote mine. While I'm not the downvoter, it appears you didn't explained well your **actual** issue in your question, this, making your own answer nowhere near the asked question (I assume, based on the many additional informations that should belong to the question)